# Passing variable information from data previously updated via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a tool that describes the tables in a database through a web interface. I have a drop down where the user selects a version of the database. That selection populates a form select with the columns from the table. The problem is, when I select a column from that list, which pulls appropriately through Ajax, the results of the select are run against my default database from my else statement, rather than the database selected by the user. I have a breakdown somewhere when I try to send the db version to search.php

My jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", '.version', function() {
    var myVersion = $(this).attr('id');
    //$.post('conn.php', {'myVersion': myVersion});
    $('#select').load('selectdb.php', {'myVersion': myVersion});
    $.post('search.php', {'dbVersion': myVersion});
});

$(document).on('click', '#search', function() {
    var formData = $('#schemaSearch').serializeArray();
    $('#searchResults').load('search.php', formData);
});
```

selectdb.php:

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

if ($myVersion == '9.93') {
    $dbVersion = 'goals';
} else {
    $dbVersion = 'jamfsoftware';
}

$columnOnly = mysql_query("select distinct(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_schema='" . $dbVersion . "' order by column_name");
$result = mysql_query("select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='" . $dbVersion . "' order by column_name");


   echo  '<option></option>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($columnOnly)) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['column_name'] . ">" . $row['column_name'] . "</option>";
    } 

?>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    include('selectdb.php');

    $lookingFor = $_POST['select'];
    if (isset($_POST['dbVersion'])) {
        $dbVersion = $_POST['dbVersion'];
    } else {
        $dbVersion = 'jamfsoftware';
    }



    $lookingForQuery = mysql_query("select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='" . $dbVersion . "' and column_name like '" . $lookingFor . "'");
    echo $dbVersion;
?>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: ^...this is quite important, specially since you're writing a database tool. :o

Comment: Yep, I agree @MagnusEriksson. This is super beginning prototype stage from very old code I just picked back up. I will be cleaning things up next. Right now I'm just trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't wait.. do it correctly from the start. You will have a much harder time going back and refactoring everything. There's _**never**_ an excuse to knowingly write deprecated and insecure code.

Comment: I have a few issues with your code: 1- please add the minimal _html_ part. 2- in the selectdb.php you should have at leaset this line: `$myVersion = $_POST['myVersion'];` but you have not declared `$myVersion` variable at all. 3- in your javascript, in the `$(document).on("click", '.version', function() {` function, why you have this line at the end `$.post('search.php', {'dbVersion': myVersion});`. what is your purpose for this line?

Comment: @EshanT thanks for taking a look. Do I not declare myVersion here? $(document).on("click", '.version', function() {
    var myVersion = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#select').load('selectdb.php', {'myVersion': myVersion});

Comment: Also, the post was just an attempt to send that value to search.php. It doesn't work, obviously. I'll remove it, but that's what I was attempting to accomplish